# To clear textbox values

Tags: c#

Text box is not getting cleared

I have entered time as 3 and all the other values. Without saving I have to change the time as 2 and the other textbox values should be cleared

```
    private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
      textBox2.Text = "";
      textBox3.Text = "";
      textBox4.Text = "";
      textBox5.Text = "";
      textBox6.Text = "";
      textBox7.Text = "";
      textBox8.Text = "";
      textBox9.Text = "";
      textBox10.Text = "";
      textBox1.Text = "";
    }

    private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
      textBox2.Text = "";
      textBox3.Text = "";
      textBox4.Text = "";
      textBox5.Text = "";
      textBox6.Text = "";
      textBox7.Text = "";
      textBox8.Text = "";
      textBox9.Text = "";
      textBox10.Text = "";
      textBox1.Text = "";
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on the lines that should be clearing the textbox? Are those breakpoints being hit?

Comment: Can you please explain a complete scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this function to empty all the textboxes in the current form:

```
    public void ClearTextBoxes()
    {
        foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
        {
            if (x is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)x).Text = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```